# add a column based on values in three other columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame ('ju') that has three columns and 230 rows. The first two columns represent a pair of objects. The third column includes one of those objects. I'd like to add the fourth column which will contain the second object from that pair, as shown below.

[image]

I wrote a code to identify the value for the forth column (loser), but it does not give me any output when I run it.

```
for (i in 1:230) {
  if (ju$winner[i]==ju$letter2[i]) {
    paste(ju$letter1[i])
  } else {
    paste (ju$letter2[i])
  }
}
```

I can not see what is wrong with the code. Also I would appreciate if you can suggest how I could create this fourth column directly into my data frame, instead of creating a separate vector and then adding it to the data frame. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with tidyverse:

```
dt <- tibble(l1 = c("a", "c", "t", "r"),
             l2 = c("c", "b", "j", "k"),
             winner = c("a", "b", "j", "k"))
dt <- dt %>% 
  mutate(looser = if_else(winner == l1, l2, l1))
(dt)
```

Comment: So this solution worked for me. Not sure why the first and second solution wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print to console, you'll need to add:

```
cat(ju$letter1[i])
```

or

```
print(ju$letter1[i])
```

Regarding the New Column question, a possible solution (sub-optimal to use a for loop here -- See suggestion from @lab_rat_kid):

```
ju$NewColumn = NA
for (i in 1:230) {
  if (ju$winner[i]==ju$letter2[i]) {
    ju$NewColumn[i] <- ju$letter1[i]
  } else {
    ju$NewColumn[i] <- ju$letter2[i]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @uceslc0. The answer works well on the recreated data from the question. But when I apply it to my data, it gives errors: Error: unexpected ')' in:
"  } else {
    ju$NewColumn[i]<-ju$portfolio_b_label[i])"
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}" . I probably have a problem with the data in my dataset, as I had the same thing with the answer lab_rat_kid provided (see my comment there). I'll upvote your answer for now.

Comment: just to make it clear the names for letter1 and letter2 in my dataset are portfolio_a_label and portfolio_b_label.

Comment: Yes, there is an issue with your code snippet. If you remove the ) after { ju$NewColumn[i]<-ju$portfolio_b_label[i] it would work fine!

Comment: yes, worked. I have no idea how I added that bracket. I thought I just copied/pasted.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it without a `for` loop:

```
ju$loser <- ifelse(ju$winner %in% ju$letter1, ju$letter2, ju$letter1)
```

Gives:

```
> ju
  letter1 letter2 winner loser
1       a       c      a     c
2       c       b      b     c
3       t       j      j     t
4       r       k      k     r
```

Comment: lab_rat_kid, I liked the simplicity of your answer, so tried it first. But I have a problem. When the object (for the 4th column) is to be selected from the 2nd column, it works well. The problem appears when the 4th column should be populated with the object from the 1st column. The output still uses the object from 2nd column. So the 4th column is identical to 2nd column. Here is  the code I am using (just in case I made a mistake when transcribing the actual names in my table ju$loser1 <- ifelse(ju$winner %in% ju$portfolio_a_label, ju$portfolio_b_label, ju$portfolio_a_label)

Comment: BTW I recreated the example from my question/your answer and it works well, so I can't figure out what happens when I am using it on my data frame.

Comment: The variables in all columns in my actual dataset are 'chr', if it has any importance.